# Style is not applying

Tags: android, android-edittext, styles, toolbar

I have been trying to apply style to a EditText and a Toolbar and it seems not to work, it's the first time that is happening to me, here is my code for styles:

```
<resources>

<style name="WifiHome" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/light_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/WifiHomeTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="WifiHomeBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
    <item name="background">@color/dark_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/dark_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/WifiHomeTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="WifiHomeTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
</style>

<style name="WifiHomeTextAppearance.Large" parent="@style/WifiHomeTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Here the declaration of EditText:

```
    <EditText
    style="@style/EditTextStyle"
    android:id="@+id/txtPass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
    android:layout_below="@id/lblPass"/>
```

And the declaration of toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/WifiHomeBarStyle"
android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/dark_blue"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

Simply it doesn't work, no effect.

Comment: Where do these non-android attributes (`colorControlNormal`, etc) come from?

Comment: These are Android attributes.

Comment: `colorControlNormal` is available only from the API 21. Do you use a corresponding device?

Comment: If i put "colorControlNormal" and so on directly in the style "WifiHome" it works and im using api 19 device.

Comment: Hm... OK, I understood. You're right, it will work with the API 19 through appcompat. If you'll check the styles, you'll find the `colorControlNormal` in `Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat`, which is the parent for `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` (through `Theme.AppCompat` and `Base.Theme.AppCompat`), and this is the reason, why you can change it. But if you'll check the parents of `Widget.AppCompat.EditText`, there isn't `colorControlNormal` attribute. I am sure, this is the reason.

Comment: And what can I do to change the EditText color without using colorControl?

Comment: `android:background` on `EditText`. Also, if your `EditText` and `Toolbar` are in different activities, you can define a separate theme, for example `ANewTheme parent= WifiHome `, set `colorControl` in this new theme and apply the theme to the corresponding activity (the activity with `EditText`) in `AndroidManifest`.

Comment: @Grender What worked for you? You need to customize Theme.AppCompat* styles to customize individual widgets?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your code like this,

```
 <style name="WifiHome" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/light_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/WifiHomeTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/dark_blue</item>
 </style>
```

OR something like this in your EditText definition,

```
 style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText
```

Comment: It works, but I need different colors for Toolbar and EditText.

Comment: If I put " style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText" in my EditText definition, it will be the same.

Comment: okay, then try setting theme attribute for your Toolbar. Forget style attribute and set android:theme

Comment: I have just tried it, it works on the Toolbar but not in EditText.

Comment: You can keep the first option of my answer for your EditText and keep theme for your Toolbar and have different values for both of them as you want.

Comment: I thought that, but I want to know why styles are not working well.